# Split whitespaces in a string and store them in table in C without libraries

Tags: c, string, malloc

I had a assignment for my class last week where I had to split a string with the spaces, tabs et `\n` as separators and store every "word" in an array. I think I'm very close but my output is very weird so if someone could tell what did I forget, it would be nice. Only thing is I can only use `malloc`.

```
char    **ft_split_whitespaces(char *str)
{
    int     i;
    int     j;
    int     k;
    char    **tab;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = 0;
    tab = (char**)malloc(sizeof(*tab) * (ft_nb_words(str) + 1));
    while (str[i])
    {
        while (str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\t' || str[i] == '\n')
            i++;
        if (str[i])
        {
            if ((tab[j] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (ft_len_word(str + i) + 1))) == NULL)
                return (NULL);
            while (k < ft_len_word(str + i))
                tab[j][k++] = str[i++];
            tab[j++][k] = '\0';
            k = 0;
        }
    }
    tab[j] = NULL;
    return (tab);
}
```

The functions returning the length of a word and the number of words work fine so I think the problem comes from the main function.

Comment: Note that if a `malloc()` in the loop fails, you leak memory.  That is not, however, part of your current problem.

Comment: This loop is dubious: `while (k < ft_len_word(str + i))
            tab[j][k++] = str[i++];` — you're incrementing `i` as you go, but you don't want to be doing that, I think.  Probably capture the length once outside the loop; then you might be OK.  But as it stands, I think you have problems.

Comment: Ok that was this, thank you very much

Comment: And how could i solve the memory leaking problem ?

Comment: You’d need a loop to free already allocated strings plus another call to free the vector of pointers before you execute the error return.  Strictly, you should error check the first allocation too.

Comment: Is `malloc` allowed or does it violate the "no library" constraint?

Comment: is `char *str` really writeable? because if so, all you need to manage is a sequence of pointers, and dropping terminators in the appropriate places of the original string.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily handled if you take one pointer to point the last occurrence of specific character('' '\n' \t).

```
   char    **ft_split_whitespaces(char *str)
    {
    int     i;
    int     j;
    int     k;
    char    **tab;
    char *prevToken=str;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = 0;
    tab = (char**)malloc(sizeof(*tab) * (ft_nb_words(str) + 1));
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {

        if(str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\t' || str[i] == '\n')
        {
            i++;
            if ((tab[j] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (ft_len_word(prevToken) + 1))) == NULL)
                return (NULL);

            while (k < ft_len_word(prevToken) &&
                (prevToken[k] !=' ' &&  prevToken[k] != '\t' &&  prevToken[k] != '\n'))
                tab[j][k] = prevToken[k++];

            printf("tab=%s\n", tab[j]);
            k = 0;
            j++;
            prevToken=(str+i);
        }
        else{
           i++;
         }
    }

      /* to handle the last word */
            if ((tab[j] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (ft_len_word(prevToken) + 1))) == NULL)
                return (NULL);

            while (k < ft_len_word(prevToken) &&
                (prevToken[k] !=' ' &&  prevToken[k] != '\t' &&  prevToken[k] != '\n'))
                tab[j][k] = prevToken[k++];
            printf("tab=%s\n", tab[j]);


    tab[j] = NULL;
    return (tab);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code contains an implementation of some useful C functions.

The function you search is `strtok()`. In the code are implemented also the functions `strspn()` and `strpbrk()` because `strtok()` uses them.

The best way to solve this kind of problems is to study the implementation of C standard functions.

The code stores the copies of max 100 token (the extracted words).

You have to remember that the function `strtok()` modifies the content of the source string inserting '\0' to terminate the strings found.

The functions here implemented are:

- mystrtok()
- mystrspn()
- mystrpbrk()

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* for the use of strcpy fn */
#include <malloc.h>

char * mystrtok (char * s, char * delim);
size_t mystrspn (const char *s, const char *accept);
char * mystrpbrk (const char *s, const char *accept);

char * mystrpbrk (const char *s, const char *accept)
{
    while (*s != '\0')
    {
        const char *a = accept;
        while (*a != '\0')
            if (*a++ == *s)
                return (char *) s;
        ++s;
    }

    return NULL;
}

size_t mystrspn (const char *s, const char *accept)
{
    const char *p;
    const char *a;
    size_t count = 0;

    for (p = s; *p != '\0'; ++p)
    {
        for (a = accept; *a != '\0'; ++a)
            if (*p == *a)
                break;
        if (*a == '\0')
            return count;
        else
            ++count;
    }

    return count;
}

char * mystrtok (char *s, char *delim)
{
    char *token;
    static char *olds;

    if (s == NULL) {
        s = olds;
    }

    /* Scan leading delimiters.  */
    s += mystrspn (s, delim);
    if (*s == '\0')
    {
        olds = s;
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Find the end of the token.  */
    token = s;
    s = mystrpbrk (token, delim);
    if (s == NULL)
    {
        /* This token finishes the string.  */
        while(*olds)
            olds++;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Terminate the token and make OLDS point past it.  */
        *s = '\0';
        olds = s + 1;
    }
    return token;
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "I have an orange\tYou have some bananas\nShe has three pineapples\n";
    char * x = NULL;

    int cnt=0,i;


    char **store;

    /* Stores a max of 100 strings */
    store = malloc(sizeof(char *)*100);

    /* The total space for the tokens is
       max the entire string + '\0' */
    store[0] = malloc(strlen(str)+1);

    /* Extract the first token */
    x=mystrtok(str," \n");
    while(x) {
        printf("Storing %s\n",x);

        /* Store a copy of the token */
        strcpy(store[cnt],x);
        store[cnt+1]=store[cnt]+strlen(x)+1;
        cnt++;

        /* extract the next token */
        x=mystrtok(NULL," \n\t");
    }

    for(i=0;i<cnt;i++)
        printf("Stored %s\n",store[i]);

    free(store[0]);
    free(store);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is inefficient as you call `ft_len_word` far too many times, but it does not seem broken apart from the undefined behavior on `malloc` failures.

The problem might lie in your versions of `ft_len_word` or `ft_nb_words`. You should post a full program exhibiting the problem for a proper investigation.

Here is a modified version that does not use these functions:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int ft_is_space(char c) {
    return (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n');
}

char **ft_split_whitespaces(const char *str) {
    int i, j, k, len, in_space, nb_words;
    char **tab;

    nb_words = 0;
    in_space = 1;
    for (i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
        if (ft_is_space(str[i]) {
            in_space = 1;
        } else {
            nb_words += in_space;
            in_space = 0;
        }
    }
    tab = malloc(sizeof(*tab) * (nb_words + 1));
    if (tab != NULL) {
        i = 0;
        j = 0;
        while (str[i]) {
            while (ft_is_space(str[i]))
                i++;
            if (str[i]) {
                for (len = 1; str[i + len] && !ft_is_space(str[i + len]); len++)
                     continue;
                if ((tab[j] = malloc(sizeof(*tab[j]) * (len + 1))) == NULL) {
                     while (j > 0)
                         free(tab[--j]);
                     free(tab);
                     return NULL;
                }
                for (k = 0; k < len; k++)
                    tab[j][k] = str[i + k];
                tab[j++][len] = '\0';
                i += len;
            }
        }
        tab[j] = NULL;
    }
    return tab;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your version of `strtok()` if you do not want to use the library function or need a different functionality than the one provided by `strtok()`.

Below is a simple string tokenizer, which, unlike the standard library's `strtok()`, still returns a value in case of consecutive delimiters. I used this function to parse CSV files, which sometimes include empty cells, hence consecutive `,` characters. Standard library's `strtok()` did not work for me, so I had to implement my own function.

I used other helper functions, which are now part of [a simple string library I maintain on GitHub, called zString](https://github.com/fnoyanisi/zString).

Below is how it behaves

```
Example Usage
      char str[] = "A,B,,,C";
      printf("1 %s\n",zstring_strtok(s,","));
      printf("2 %s\n",zstring_strtok(NULL,","));
      printf("3 %s\n",zstring_strtok(NULL,","));
      printf("4 %s\n",zstring_strtok(NULL,","));
      printf("5 %s\n",zstring_strtok(NULL,","));
      printf("6 %s\n",zstring_strtok(NULL,","));

  Example Output
      1 A
      2 B
      3 ,
      4 ,
      5 C
      6 (null)
```

and the code

```
char *zstring_strtok(char *str, const char *delim) {
    static char *static_str=0;      /* var to store last address */
    int index=0, strlength=0;       /* integers for indexes */
    int found = 0;                  /* check if delim is found */

    /* delimiter cannot be NULL
    * if no more char left, return NULL as well
    */
    if (delim==0 || (str == 0 && static_str == 0))
        return 0;

    if (str == 0)
        str = static_str;

    /* get length of string */
    while(str[strlength])
        strlength++;

    /* find the first occurrence of delim */
    for (index=0;index<strlength;index++)
        if (str[index]==delim[0]) {
            found=1;
            break;
        }

    /* if delim is not contained in str, return str */
    if (!found) {
        static_str = 0;
        return str;
    }

    /* check for consecutive delimiters
    *if first char is delim, return delim
    */
    if (str[0]==delim[0]) {
        static_str = (str + 1);
        return (char *)delim;
    }

    /* terminate the string
    * this assignment requires char[], so str has to
    * be char[] rather than *char
    */
    str[index] = '\0';

    /* save the rest of the string */
    if ((str + index + 1)!=0)
        static_str = (str + index + 1);
    else
        static_str = 0;

        return str;
}
```